# prove the set has maximum element

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have proven the following exercise using the sequential definition of the supremum of a non empty and bounded above subset of real numbers and limit of sequences.The difficulty comes with the demand of my professor at elementary analysis to prove it using neither sequences nor limits of sequences.

> If $\emptyset\neq A\subset\mathbb R$, with $\sup A\lt 1$ with the property that $\forall a\in A,\ \forall b\in A\ \left(a \lt b\Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}\in A\right)$, then $A$ has a maximum element or equivalently $\sup A\in A$.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there is a unique element $x_0\in A$ such that $(\sup A)^2<x_0\le \sup A$; if there are two elements $x<y$ of $A$ such that $(\sup A)^2<x<y\le \sup A$, then $\sup A<\frac x y\in A$ leads to a contradiction. And it there is none, $(\sup A)^2$ becomes an upper bound of $A$ that is less than $\sup A$, also leading to a contradiction. Now, since $x_0$ is an upper bound of $A$, we have $x_0\ge \sup A$, and it follows that $x_0=\sup A$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: awesome!!!!Iyou are my hero!!!

Comment: I hope it was helpful !